# How to convert enum to list with where statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to get values from enum which is not equal to 1 and display them in to dropdown list.
I mean is that, I do not want to show `Done` and it's value.

```
public enum Statement
{
    Done= 1,
    Waiting= 2,
    Rejected= 3
}
```

Comment: I found sth to get them with IEnumerable. Enum.GetValues(typeof(Statement)).Cast<Statement>(); but I do not need all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with LINQ like:

```
List<string> list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Statement))
                        .Cast<Statement>()
                        .Where(r=> (int) r != 1)
                        .Select(t=> t.ToString())
                        .ToList();
```